# Pressure as momentum flux versus momentum of fluid flow

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I've read in multiple sources (for example, Thorne and Blandford, **Modern Classical Physics**, pg 83 and Schutz, **A First Course on General Relativity** pg 92) that the stress components of the stress-energy 4-tensor represent momentum flux across surfaces normal to the space coordinate axes.  Simply put, *pressure is momentum flux.*  If that is the case, how does this relate to the following simple example?

Consider an incompressible dry fluid of mass density $\rho$ flowing uniformly in the positive $x$ direction with velocity $v$.  The momentum $\phi$ per unit volume is $\phi=v\rho.$  The volume of fluid crossing a unit area per unit time  of a fixed plane normal to the velocity is simply $v$.  So the momentum flux per unit area is $v\phi=v^2\rho.$

Now consider a tank filled with the same fluid with a hole in the side a distance $h$ below the free surface.  The pressure is give by $P=hg\rho.$  This can be seen by considering a column of fluid $h$ units high and of unit base, then observing that pressure is isotropic.  If pressure is momentum flux this would seem to mean
$$P=v\phi=v^2\rho=hg\rho.$$
So
$$v=\sqrt{gh}.$$

To displace a unit area of surface a distance $\Delta x$ against the pressure would do $\Delta W=P\Delta x.$  The mass of fluid in the displaced volume is
$$\Delta m=\Delta x\rho.$$

Reversing this argument shows that the kinetic energy imparted to $\Delta m$ is $$\Delta W=\Delta T=\frac{v^2}{2}\Delta m=\frac{v^2}{2}\rho\Delta x=hg\rho\Delta x=P\Delta x.$$
So the velocity of the fluid as it leaves the tank is
$$v=\sqrt{2gh}.$$

This is called Torricelli's formula.

Why is the momentum flux equal to twice the pressure?

Comment: The reaction force of the wall on the fluid would be inducing a momentum flux into the fluid cancelling the momentum flux induced by the fluid on the wall.  When there is a hole in the wall, the reaction force is not there.

Comment: It seems to me that the author is invoking the context of fluid dynamics, wherein one would see from the Navier-Stokes equations the momentum equation: $\rho D_t\mathbf{v}=\nabla p$ and hence the pressure is a flux term for the momentum, $\rho\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: I think the motivation is more elementary.  Fill Einstein's mythical interstellar elevator with water and accelerate it at $9.8 ms^2.$  The force per unit area of the floor on the water is the pressure.  It is also the rate of change of momentum.